# After uploading the file with git, the format is wrong

Tags: git, github, markdown

I use git to upload README documents.
What is displayed locally is

[image]

After the file is uploaded, it is displayed as:

[image]

How can I solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github displays the rendered markdown in readmes as a convenience but it doesn't actually change the content of the file, so the file is still exactly as you uploaded it.

As for the markdown itself, put a blank line after that first header and it should render more correctly.

You may also have to get rid of the leading spaces on your top level numbered list lines but not sure off the top of my head and I'm on my phone right now so can't test easily.

Comment: I suggest also adding a space between the hashes and the title: `#### Directeory`. This may be required for rendering, but even if it isn't, it's a lot more readable in raw text form which is [a design goal](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/): "The overriding design goal for Markdown’s formatting syntax is to make it as readable as possible. The idea is that a Markdown-formatted document should be publishable as-is, as plain text, without looking like it’s been marked up with tags or formatting instructions."